# Get value from a UISlider inside a Cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uislider

I have a `tableView` with custom cells in it, each cell has a `UISlider`.

Now I want to create a method to get the values of those `UISliders`, but I don't know how to access each cell and its slider value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First add a tag to each slider so you no which slider is which:

`slider.tag = 0 //Can be any unique integer`

Then register a method for slider changes:

`[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderUpdate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Finally in your method

```
-(void)sliderUpdate:(UISlider *)sender {
    int value = sender.value;
    int tag = sender.tag;
}
```

Tag will now be the same unique integer you used before.  It is a way of identifying the element.

Comment: should i switch between tags inside that sliderUpdate? or just "IF" my way through my 13 tags ? :P

Comment: I would actually use a loop: `for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++){ if (i == slider.tag) {//this is the cell that corresponds to this slider}}`

Answer (score 0):

ummmm, few possibilities:

1) keep a reference to all the cells in your UITableViewController

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, right before returning the cell, add it to an array you have as a property on your UITableViewController

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
      //Set up your cell

      [[self allCells] addObject:cell];
      return cell;
}

-(void)getSliderValues {
    for(CustomCell *cell in [self allCells]){
        //Here is your cell
        cell;
    }
}
```

2) use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
-(void)getSliderValues {
    int section = 0;
    int numberOfCells = [self tableView:[self tableView] numberOfRowsInSection:section];

    for(int row = 0; row < numberOfCells; row++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];

        //Here is your cell
        CustomCell *cell = [self tableView:[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Note that in this method, if you are using reuse identifiers, you probably wont be getting the cell you want/need.